# Python pandas dataframe transpose and column as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe say,

```
    col_a    col_b    col_c    col_d
0    10       A        10       10
1    20       B        20       20
2    30       C        30       30
3    40       D        40       40
```

I am trying to transpose it to,

```
       A    B    C    D
col_a 10   20    30  40
col_c 10   20    30  40
col_d 10   20    30  40
```

Comment: please check my answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
new_df=df.set_index('col_b').T
print(new_df)

col_b   A   B   C   D
col_a  10  20  30  40
col_c  10  20  30  40
col_d  10  20  30  40
```

---

You can remove the name of columns doing:

```
new_df.columns.name=None
print(new_df)

        A   B   C   D
col_a  10  20  30  40
col_c  10  20  30  40
col_d  10  20  30  40
```

Also you can use [DataFrame.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df.pivot_table(columns='col_b')
```

---

```
col_b   A   B   C   D
col_a  10  20  30  40
col_c  10  20  30  40
col_d  10  20  30  40
```